# Cannot instantiate abstract class, but I have

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

First time caller here.  I'm new to C++ and have tried for hours to figure this one out.  Sorry to ask what seems a common question.  I couldn't find the answer for the life of me.

I am getting the following compile error in visual studio:

```
error C2259: 'Node' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'void Node::printValue(void)' : is abstract.
```

It is my understanding that this means the pure virtual function that I created has not been implemented in a child class.  From everything what I can see, it has been implemented in the intNode child.  What am I doing wrong here?  The code is below.  Thanks in advance!

In Node.h:

```
class Node {            
protected: 
    Node* nextNodePtr;  

public:
    Node();
    Node* getNextNodePtr(void);
    void setNextNodePtr(Node*);
    ~Node();
    virtual void printValue() = 0; 
};

class intNode : public Node {
    int nodeInteger;       
public:
    virtual void printValue()
    {
        cout << "***" << endl;
    }

    intNode(int i) 
    { 
        nodeInteger = i; 
    }
};
```

In Node.cpp:

```
void intNode::printValue() 
{
    cout << "It's an int: " << nodeInteger << endl;
}

void Node::printValue()
{
    cout << "This is just here fix compile error" << nodeInteger << endl;
}
```

Edit...sorry, I forgot to add this bit.  The error is pointing to this section in main

```
int main()
{
Node* firstNode = new Node;     <---- this line is where the error points
firstNode = new intNode;
intNode* intNode = new intNode;
```

Comment: Where's the code that produces the error? And why are you defining `intNode::printValue()` twice? And why are you (attempting to) use `nodeInteger` in a member of `Node`?

Comment: You seem to have two definitions of `intNode::printValue()` (one inline in the header, and one in Node.cpp). This will probably give you an error at link time, but I doubt it's causing the one you're seeing. It might sound silly, but are you sure you're trying to create an `intNode`, and not a `Node`?

Comment: Apart from all the mentioned errors, I imagine that you are trying to create an instance of Node, but node is abstract. Use Node* node = new intNode( 5 ); Don't use Node node = intNode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to create instances of abstract classes. The message says so, you know it, so don't do it.

```
int main()
{
Node* firstNode; // do not create Node instance here. 
                 // It's a compile time error and even if not,
                 // it would have been a memory leak.

firstNode = new intNode;
intNode* intNode = new intNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement is incorrect.

> It is my understanding that this means the pure virtual function that I created has not been implemented in a child class.

The error means that `void Node::printValue(void)` is pure virtual (i.e. `void foo() = 0`) in the `Node class`. This makes the Node class abstract. Since you cannot instantiate abstract classes, you see the error.

Additionally, as has been mentioned in the comments, you have defined `void intNode::printValue()` twice. That is incorrect.

Comment: You're allowed to provide a definition for a pure virtual method in C++, in order to have a derived class call the parent class's implementation.